# IKPictureTaker - Set Opening Tab

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-graphics, ikpicturetaker

I'm using an IKPictureTaker in one of my apps, and when it opens it has four selectable tabs (Defaults, Recents, Camera, Other). I'd like it to be set to the Defaults tab when it opens up, but from the class reference it seems as though you can only open it to the Camera tab, with `– beginPictureTakerSheetForWindow:withDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:`, or the Recents tab, with `– popUpRecentsMenuForView:withDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:`.

Is there any way to programmatically set the tab it opens to?